# Axios doesn't GET data in React but it does in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My JSON looks like this

```
{
    "towns" :[
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "location": "Japanifornia",
            "status" : 1
        },
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "location" : "Kohonohakatsuki",
            "status" : 2
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "location" : "Taxis",
            "status" : 5
        }
        ]
}
```

The problem occured when I use axios in React. It should return the result like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "location": "Japanifornia",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": "Kohonohakatsuki",
        "status": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "location": "Taxis",
        "status": 5
    }
]
```

The problem happened, I used axios in componentWillMount() in React to get request from localhost:7777/towns . 
But the request never been made, I checked the log from json-server and no request occured when I load or reload localhost:3000 which contains component that do GET request.
 I already check in other application ranging from Firefox to node console. 
All application return what it should beside React which return nothing

This is my componentWillMount

```
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('127.0.0.1:7777/towns')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => this.setState({data:result,isLoading: false}))
  }
```

Comment: use componenentDidMount.Also check in network tab and make sure you are component rendering

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Too bad, nothing changed.

Comment: Check your JS console. If the request isn't being made then there's a js issue.

Comment: Get 404 error on axios and valid JSON parse error on fetch

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution finally!! It because of my stupid mistake.

I assumed the result is {[dataHere]} but it actually [] array.

The error occured because the result is JS array not Json array.

Answer (score 0):

documentation suggest to use Ajax call inside componentDidMount, inside componentWillMount u can initialize your data with an empy array. I think what you get from the call is an object with an attribute towns witch contains an array. To get the data try to set the state with result.towns. in componentDidMount do `this.setState({ towns: result.towns})` and in componentWillMount do `this.setState({ towns: []})`. Add a console log in the render method and you should see the data.

Comment: Um,I decleared state in the constructor. When componentDidMount do the request,axios send 404 error but never made the requqest to json-server,but fetch() returned JSON parse error on valid JSON.

Comment: Your axios do the get on port 7777 but the server is running on port 3000?! Try to make the call by using another client..curl or postman for example

Comment: Json-api is on 7777 but react is on 3000. I already called with Insomnia and browser. Every application returned json but axios.